# ClientScriptManager loads scripts later, after the client script is loaded

Tags: jquery, web-controls, client-side-scripting

I am creating a custom webcontrol, in that control's OnPreRender registering the Jquery script like this

> clientScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptResource(typeof(mycontrol),
>   "jquery")

in my aspx script i am using the jquery function.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function () { });
  </script>
```

it show the `$ is undifined`, when the control comes to client script, the js is not loaded.

this there is any way to register the script file, before the client script loads ?

Comment: `$ is undefined` occurs when jQuery library is not loaded before the script.

Comment: Where is jQuery defined? Is it in the Web App's project or Custom Control's project?

Comment: @Praveen jQuery defined in Custom Control's project, injecting that using clientScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptResource(typeof(mycontrol), "jquery")

Comment: Did you add jQuery.js file as an Embedded Resource in the Custom Control's Project?

Comment: @Praveen, yes i did.the problem is the js file loads after client script executed.